# unable to recreate catplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina'], 'Y': [13,19,52,14,12,12]})`

```
       X   Y
0  Jason  13
1  Molly  19
2   Tina  52
3  Jason  14
4   Tina  12
5   Tina  12
```

I want to recreate the catplot functionality of seaborn library in matplotlib, like:

```
sns.catplot(x='X', y='Y', kind="box", data=df)
```

so I do:

```
plt.boxplot(df.X, df.Y)
```

but this doesn't work, I get an error:

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

How can I achieve the same results in matplotlib?

I am doing this in matplotlib, because with seaborn, I have to change x manually and I want to change x dynamically with a for-loop

Comment: You can try `df.boxplot(column='Y', by='X')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent, because seaborn groups the data by x first. When using matplotlib you would need to do the grouping manually,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'X':['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jason', 'Tina', 'Tina'],
                          'Y': [13,19,52,14,12,12]})

plt.boxplot([col.Y.values for n, col in df.groupby("X")])
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you pls explain what you do with: col.Y.values for n, col in df.groupby("X")?

Comment: This groups the values by name. The result will be a list of lists `[[13,14], [19], [52,12,12]]`.

Comment: I understand. However, I am a bit of a noob, can you please point me to some link I can refer by myself, to the technique you used to group? I have never seen this kind of usage

Comment: Here is [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) documented. This is essentially what [seaborn does](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/categorical.py#L206) under the hood (though [it uses](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/222d54467685b96ec9fabb32a9b382e35c745b1f/seaborn/utils.py#L536) `.unique` really.)